# How to paste a column from one sheet to another in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column with unknown number of rows in one sheet, i'd like to copy it and paste on another sheet. As far number of rows is unknown I define it as a variable:

```
Sub Official()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Set currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row
LastCol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

Sheets("Type_1").Range("D8" & "D" & LastRow).Copy
Sheets(1).Range("A2").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=True
End Sub
```

I get an error to this macro, maybe someone can help me?

Comment: You've missed colon. Change `Range("D8" & "D" & LastRow).Copy` to `Range("D8:D" & LastRow).Copy`. Btw, in your code `lastrow` defined for *active sheet*, while you copy data from sheet `Type_1`. Is it correct behaviour?

Comment: Thank you! I changed, but it does not copy anything now. Could it be a problem with LastRow variable definition? 
I should probably define it for Type_1. The problem is that I have to copy columns from many different sheets, do I have to define lastrow for each of them?

Comment: in your code `lastrow` defined for *active sheet*, while you copy data from sheet `Type_1`. Try to use `LastRow = Sheets("Type_1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row`

Comment: unfortunately even after changing Range as Range("D8:D" & LastRow).Copy and LastRow = Sheets("Type_1").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row it does not do Copy/Paste, but does not give an error too.

Comment: try to add line `MsgBox LastRow` just before copying. What result you would get? Btw, maybe you should determine lastrow using column `D`, like this: `LastRow = Sheets("Type_1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row`?

Comment: Thank You!
LastRow = Sheets("Type_1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row helped, now it works fine. I just wonder, if is necessary to define LastRow for each sheet (Type_2, Type_3 etc.)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48881/discussion-between-simoco-and-ale)

Comment: @Ale please would you edit your question to include details of the error message, on what line of code the error happens, what the desired result is...

Comment: @Philip the mistake was in this 2 lines:
Sheets("Type_1").Range("D8" & "D" & LastRow).Copy
and LastRow = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row. As simoco said should be:
Range("D8:D" & LastRow).Copy and LastRow = Sheets("Type_1").Range("D" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

Answer (score 0):

you could try:

```
Sub Official()
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim srcLastRow As Long

    Set currentsheet = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    ' handle Office 2007+ with more than 65536 rows...
    lastrow = Range("A" & currentsheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column

    ' find out how many rows there are in the source sheet
    srcLastRow = Sheets("Type_1").Range("D" & Sheets("Type_1").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    ' copy from the course sheet to the currentSheet in the range specified
    Sheets("Type_1").Range("D8:" & "D" & srcLastRow).Copy Destination:=currentsheet.Range("A" & lastrow)

    ' or maybe you want:
    ' Sheets("Type_1").Range("D8:" & "D" & srcLastRow).Copy Destination:=currentsheet.Cells(lastrow, LastCol)

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You, Philip, it is already solved, but i think also your solution works fine!